# neo4j cypher retrieve properties of related nodes to path's nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have the following sample data,http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ktfn9n ,
and i have 2 questions:

**1.about the following query:** (tries to find all the sub-paths inside the Hits path of specific pages)

```
MATCH (step1:Hit)
WHERE step1.page =~ '(?i)(.*home.*)'
MATCH (step2:Hit)
WHERE step2.page =~ '(?i)(.*register.*)'
MATCH (step3:Hit)
WHERE step3.page =~ '(?i)(.*buy.*)'
MATCH path=step1-[:NEXT*]->step2-[:NEXT*]->step3
WITH filter(n IN NODES(path) 
        WHERE n:Hit AND n.page =~ '(?i)(.*home.*|.*register.*|.*buy.*)')   AS filtered
WITH extract(v IN filtered| { page:lower(v.page)}) AS ex UNWIND ex AS pages
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT pages) AS hits
RETURN hits,count(hits) AS path_users_count
ORDER BY path_users_count DESC
```

as you can see in the result-set in the console: the result is:

> [ {page:"home"},  {page:"register"},  {page:"buy"}]    1

what i was expecting is:

> [ {page:"home"},  {page:"register"},  {page:"buy"}]    2

since there 2 paths with the flow of the 3 pages in the example (2 red lines in the attached image)
[image]

**2. second question**

currently i'm including the page in each Hit object, what causing to waist of resources. i want to take in the final result, the page name from the Page which related to the Hit.
(in the real database i have about 10 related nodes to each Hit, and i need to return 5 of them in the result object , so dont think that it can be included in the first MATCH right?)

Comment: with size i get 3 instead of 2

Answer (score 2):

When you `UNWIND` and then `collect(DISTINCT ...)` you're unravelling your set of arrays into one flat list and the `collect`ing it back into a single distinct list instead of one for each path match.  If you include the `path` variable in your `WITH`s you'll continue to keep them grouped by path:

```
MATCH (step1:Hit)
WHERE step1.page =~ '(?i)(.*home.*)'
MATCH (step2:Hit)
WHERE step2.page =~ '(?i)(.*register.*)'
MATCH (step3:Hit)
WHERE step3.page =~ '(?i)(.*buy.*)'
MATCH path=step1-[:NEXT*]->step2-[:NEXT*]->step3
WITH path, filter(n IN NODES(path) 
        WHERE n:Hit AND n.page =~ '(?i)(.*home.*|.*register.*|.*buy.*)')   AS filtered
WITH path, extract(v IN filtered| {page:lower(v.page)}) AS ex
UNWIND ex AS pages
WITH path, COLLECT(DISTINCT pages) AS hits
RETURN hits,count(hits) AS path_users_count
ORDER BY path_users_count DESC
```

This returns 3, though I think that might be correct because that second path in the lower left of the graphic contains two paths which match your criteria.

I'm not sure I understand your second question.  Do you mean that you want to have a label `Page` which has nodes which your `Hit` nodes reference to say what page they were hitting?  If so I don't think that's a problem.  I think you could change the beginning to this:

```
MATCH (step1:Hit)-[:HITS]->(page1:Page)
WHERE page1.url =~ '(?i)(.*home.*)'
MATCH (step2:Hit)-[:HITS]->(page2:Page)
WHERE page2.url =~ '(?i)(.*register.*)'
MATCH (step3:Hit)-[:HITS]->(page3:Page)
WHERE page3.url =~ '(?i)(.*buy.*)'
```

and the rest would be the same

Comment: hi @brian-underwood, first- thanks a lot for the detailed answer!

the problem is the flow of hits, are actually user's journey in a site, so i cant count such a flow twice. (i still have a problem if a user visited twice on the 'home' page- any help with it would be appreciated!)

with the second part i meant, that i want a hit to have only and id, and the rest of the data will be in separated labels. for each Hit, in fact, i have more related Labels: page,country,OS,device etc... and i need them all back in the response. thanks again

Comment: All neo4j experts out there. Who can help?